# My *.app file not working corretly with double click in Finder, but work with "open" command in terminal

Tags: python, macos, katalon-recorder

I record script with katalon recorder, and create another *.py file for tkinter form with button which start my script.

I built *.app file with py2app.

After I make chmod +x on MyApp.app/Content/MacOS/*

Now when I start my app in terminal like that "open myapp.app" - this open form with button, and pressing on button strating my script.

If I start my app with double-click in Finder - this open my form, but after I pressed button it has no effect. Where is a problem?

Comment: Must be something along the line of "current working directory". `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__))` might help?